# Vuex: Getter is not fetching data from external API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm trying to fetch data from an external API and display the data in my component but it is returning an empty array when I actually have data in my API.
Inside my module I have the following:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    countries = []
}

const getters = {
    allCountries: (state) => state.countries;
}

const actions = {
    //Fecth all the countries from the API
  async fetchCountries({ commit }) {
    const response = await axios.get('URL');
    commit('setCountries', response.data);
  },
}

const mutations = {
    setCountries: (state, countries) => (state.countries = countries),
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

Component:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="country in allCountries" :key="country.id">
       <small>{{country.name}}</small>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default{
    name: 'CompCountry',
    computed: mapGetters(['allCountries'])
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you get some errors in console?

Comment: I was getting one that said that the property 'allCountries' is not reactive so in my mutation I did setCountries:(state, countries) = > Vue.set(state, state.countries, countries); however, it did not work too.

Comment: your original code is `name: 'CompCountry',
computed: mapGetters(['allCountries'])` or you only removed `export default {...}` when you copied it?

Comment: I only removed export default { ... }

Comment: ah ok, but where are dispatching that action `fetchCountries` ?

Comment: This action is only getting the data

Comment: i see but you should have `this.$store.dispatch('fetchCountries')` somewhere in your code

Comment: hmmm, I'm not doing it actually! I could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to dispatch the action, to do that you should run it in a life cycle hook like `mounted` :

```
<template>
    <div v-for="country in allCountries" :key="country.id">
       <small>{{country.name}}</small>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters} from 'vuex';

export default{
    name: 'CompCountry',
    computed:{ ...mapGetters(['allCountries']},
   mounted(){
     this.$store.dispatch('fetchCountries')
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: it runs the action in order to get the data, it's like a function call, *you defined the function but you don't run it*,

Comment: You're welcome, i hope that you understand, if not don't hesitate to ask

Comment: Yes I did understand, really appreciate it!